# Chemical bond at Aluminum / Aluminum oxide interface

Tags: bond, crystal-structure, ionic-compounds

I am trying to find out what chemical bond holds aluminum oxide to the aluminum on which it forms. The only information I was able to find on the internet was in a Google book which suggested that the bond was ionic in nature.